# How to pass a numpy array of lists to a function (fancy indexing)

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, vectorization

I would like to use this function in a vectorized way with numpy:

```
def example(testing, index):
    return np.sum(testing[index], axis = 1)
```

Suppose we create our test array and the array of indices:

```
test = np.arange(0, 20)
indices = np.array([[0, 2], [1, 3], [0, 3], [1, 2], [3, 4]])
```

It does what I expect it to, summing the elements with indices in the list for each list in the array:

```
Input: example(test, indices)
Output: [2 4 3 3 7]
```

However, if I try to work with lists of indices of variable length,

```
indices = np.array([[0, 2, 3], [1, 3], [0, 3], [1, 2], [3, 4]])
Input: example(test, indices)
Output: IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type
```

I cannot get numpy to perform this function without me just iterating over the `indices` array. I understand that numpy is creating a 2-D array in the first case but not the second, but I am unsure why it is unable to perform a vectorized element-wise operation with the 1-D array. Since these arrays are actually quite large in real life and used in a parallelized function, I would like to do this in a numpy-style vectorized way as in the first example.

Comment: Thats not an array of lists, but a multidimensional array

Comment: Have you considered using a mask with entries that are one or zero? You can then use matrix multiplication to compute the sum (`dot`).

Comment: I was considering this option, but I am not sure how to create a mask from the uneven lists without a for loop or similar iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Your first version of `indices` is indeed a 2D array of integers - `indices.shape` returns `(5, 2)`, and `print(indices)` gives:

```
array([[0, 2],
       [1, 3],
       [0, 3],
       [1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
```

The second one, however, is a 1D array of **list objects**:

```
array([list([0, 2, 3]), list([1, 3]), list([0, 3]), list([1, 2]),
       list([3, 4])], dtype=object)
```

There's simply nothing to vectorize here, because those lists **are not numpy vectors**. I believe the best you could do to vectorize your operations is to create `indices` as a list of arrays rather than array of lists:

```
indices = [np.array(x) for x in [[0, 2, 3], [1, 3], [0, 3], [1, 2], [3, 4]]]
```

then redefine function to handle this:

```
def example(testing, index):
    return [ np.sum(testing[i]) for i in index ]

print(example(test, indices)) 
# prints [5, 4, 3, 3, 7]
```

Comment: Thank you for replying quickly. I understand that the elements are list objects, but the vectorization should be occurring along the numpy axis. Thus the function should be performed for all list objects at once.

Comment: The key is to avoid list comprehensions and other slow iterations.

Comment: There's no "at once". It is still a loop, only it is implemented in C, and therefore much faster than a Python loop. But that speed comes at a cost of reduced flexibility - in this particular case, the index array needs to be an array of integers, not an array of lists.

Comment: "vectorization" in `numpy` means using the compiled methods. For the most part those work with multidimensional arrays, such as your first example.  That 2nd one is 1d with list elements.  The fast compiled methods don't work with that.  There's no `axis=1`.

Comment: Thank you for your patience, this is the fastest solution so far (albeit it took my computer 14.2 microseconds while a simple list comprehension took 15.5 microseconds, so not a big difference). And I agree, what I should have written instead of “at once” is “using precompiled code”.

Comment: I was hoping there would be perhaps some way of replacing axis=1 with a clever workaround, but I suppose that the requirement to use lists eliminates any potential solutions aside from the posted one (.T, transpose(), etc.)

Comment: In general 'raggedness', lists or arrays of various length means that you can't use the 'whole-array' operations.  Making an array from indices doesn't buy you anything.  Iteration on a list of lists is faster iteration on an object array.